# DFS share(s) not visible for some Citrix SBC users

Tags: windows, citrix, dfs, share, file-server

**In short:**

Some Citrix SBC servers are experiencing the following problem

When logged in to a Citrix server and browsing to a mapped drive (eg. drive D: (mapped as \domain.local\namespace\share)) the drive apears empty. When logging off and re-logging to **another** Citrix server that is not experiencing this problem the drive is showing all content.

**A couple of known facts:**

- When someone is experiencing this issue, everyone on the same Citrix server is experiencing the same issue.
- When performing a DFS flush (dfsutil.exe cache referral flush) on this Citrix server, the issue seems to be solved for the day.
- Every day one or more Citrix servers seem to have this problem
- All Citrix servers are provisioned using Citrix PVS, so they should be identical
- When browsing to **\domain.local\namespace\share** the share is empty
- When browsing to **\domain\namespace\share** the share is oké
- when browsing to **\server\share** the share is oké
- When using CMD / Powershell the share LOOKS empty, but i can still get into the share by doing cd D:\share\subfolder . So it seems like its something cosmetic?

If i turn off ABE on DFS root level, the mapped drive D: will show alle available shares including the share this specific user has access to. Leaving ABE off is not an option though since we have a lot of shares that should not be visible to everyons.

**Envoiremental details**

- We have 19 fileservers. 16 fileservers are ROOT/Namespace servers
- All fileservers are Windows Server 2012R2 servers
- The DFS namespace is AD integrated
- The Citrix XenApp servers are all based on Windows Server 2008R2
- DFSDiag / DCDiag show no errors
- DFS structure:

---

\domain.local\Namespace

\domain.local\Namespace\Folder (no target)

\domain.local\Namespace\Folder\Shares (90 Shares. Each share has one target to a fileserver)

---

**Some workarounds that did not seem to work**

- kb/2769790
- Changing Register keys: **NoRemoteRecursiveEvents**, **NoRemoteChangeNotify**
- Changing reg keys: **FileinfoCacheLifeTime**, **FileNotFoundCacheLifetime**, **DirectoryCacheLifetime**

**When did it start?**
These problems started after deploying Microsoft patch MS17-010 (WannaCry) on the fileservers and rebooting the fileservers.

Comment: I got a similar trouble in the past, it was a dfs issue, a ping domain vs domain.local give the same output ?

Comment: ping domain gives me: Ping request could not find host. Please check the name and try again